# Change Toolbar alpha on scroll android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I want to implement an effect similar to the wikipedia and netflix apps, where the toolbar is transparent in the details activity but fades in as the user scrolls down the content. The toolbar's menu items are visible all the time.

This is my layout file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/detail_view_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The activity contents are placed inside of the NestedScrollView using a fragment transaction.

This is my details activity:

```
public class DetailActivity extends SearchBaseActivity {

    private static final String RESOURCE = "resource";

    @BindView(R.id.detail_view_container)
    NestedScrollView mContainer;
    @BindView(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        Media media = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(RESOURCE);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setTitle(null);
        }

    }

    public static Intent getStartIntent(Context context, Media media) {
        return new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class).putExtra(RESOURCE, media);
    }
}
```

Can you help me to figure this out, please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I am trying to find a nice way to get the same transition from translucent to opaque status bar when scrolling the content by simply using the CoordinatorLayout but so far I haven't find it.

I did a really basic implementation by adding a scrolllistener to the NestedScrollView:

```
NestedScrollView nsv = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.detail_view_container);
nsv.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
       int color = Color.parseColor("#FF2D2D2D"); // ideally a global variable
       if (scrollY < 256) {
            int alpha = (scrollY << 24) | (-1 >>> 8) ;
            color &= (alpha);
        }
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
});
```

This implementation starts adding opacity to the toolbar as the Y-scroll on the NestedScrollView increases.